# Implementation of Task Class in Monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios

I tried to follow this http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/Working_with_Tables_and_Cells/Part_5_-_Using_XCode,_Interface_Builder,_and_Storyboards#Adding_Code

tutorial but I faced problem in adding code stage. The issue is it cannot find Task class. Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

Initially I thought the answer would be... Add

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

At the top of the file

But.  Believe the answer to be that you need to implement a Task class.

public class Task {
public string Name {get;set;}
Public string Notes {get;set;}
public bool Done {get;set;}
}

Sorry should ave read the link more closely

Comment: Actually, I found it, after that I got another issue `        cell.TextLabel.Text = tableItems[indexPath.Row].Name;` Task file does't contain definition for file Name.